# Discord Bot: DM a specific user across shards (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have tried finding solutions for this problem but couldn't find any yet so I am going to ask here.

I've been trying to send a message to a specific user on my discord bot but since I had to add sharding into my bot it became difficult.

I added a `broadcastEval` that checks if the user exists and if it does, it sends that message. The problem there is that if that user is in 2 servers with 2 shards of my bot it will send 2 messages to that user which I don't want. Is there any other way I could be doing this?

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(async (c, { userid, embed }) => {
    let user = await c.users.fetch(userid)
    if (user) {
         user.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    }
}, { context: { userid, embed } })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code requires the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), but you could adapt to use a different way of uniquely identifying messages.

This code goes with your ShardingManager code:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
const getShardReply = async(shardId, message) => {
    message.uuid = uuidv4();
    message.type = 'getReply';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        shardingManager.shards.get(shardId).once(message.uuid, response => {
            if (response.error) return reject(response.error);
            resolve(response.data);
        });
        shardingManager.shards.get(shardId).send(message);
    });
};

const messageUser = async (userId, message, shardId = 0) => {
    return getShardReply(shardId, {data: 'messageUser', userId: userId, message: message}).catch(error => {
        if (shardingManager.shards.has(shardId+1)) return messageUser(userId, message, shardId+1);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};
```

This code goes with the shard DiscordClient code:

```
process.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.uuid) return;
    if (message.type === 'getReply') {
        if (message.data === 'messageUser') {
            const response = {uuid: message.uuid, data: {shardId: discordClient.shard.ids[0], userId: message.userId, success: false}};
            discordClient.users.fetch(message.userId).then(user => {
                if (!user) return Promise.reject(new Error('User not found'));
                user.send(message.message).then(() => {
                    response.data.success = true;
                    discordClient.shard.send(response);
                }).catch(error => {
                    response.error = error;
                    discordClient.shard.send(response);
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                response.error = error;
                discordClient.shard.send(response);
            });
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

Then just call messageUser in the ShardingManager context and it will try each shard until it succeeds.